# dataframe values multiply by 2

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a 1 dimensional dataframe:

```
           4DS.AX   A2B.AX  A2M.AX  AAC.AX  ABC.AX  ABP.AX  ACW.AX  ADH.AX  

2018-12-14  0.00    0.00    0.14    0.01    0.12    0.01    0.00    0.01
```

expected output

```
          4DS.AX    A2B.AX  A2M.AX  AAC.AX  ABC.AX  ABP.AX  ACW.AX  ADH.AX     
 2018-12-14 0.00    0.00    0.28    0.02    0.24    0.02    0.00    0.02
```

I want to multiply all the values by 2
this is my attempt:

```
   [in] df=df.iloc[0,:]*2.0
```

[out]

```
             A2B.AX      A2M.AX      AAC.AX     ABC.AX      ABP.AX  
2018-12-14  0.000.00    0.140.14    0.010.01    0.120.12....
```

Comment: check the type of data

Comment: sorry for the silly question but how do i check, I tried df.type() but it says 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'type'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the type of columns is of `str/object` type and hence it is appending rather then multiplying

Example

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({'x':['0.1']})*2
```

Output:

```
0.10.1
```

While

```
pd.DataFrame({'x':[0.1]})*2
```

Ouput

```
0.2
```

Can check the type of the column(s)

```
print(df.dtypes)
```

In order to change the type of column(s)

```
for col in ['4DS.AX','A2B.AX','A2M.AX','AAC.AX','ABC.AX','ABP.AX','ACW.AX','ADH.AX']:
    df[col] = df[col].astype('float')
```

Then, it should also work

```
df.iloc[0,:]*2.0
```